# Best way to loop through arraylist in grails

Tags: javascript, arrays, grails, arraylist, groovy

I'm sending string array to my controller that contains array of Ids in it.

```
function submit(){
        var ids = [];
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure to send data?", function(confirmed){
            if(confirmed){
                $('input[id^="tdCheckbox_"]').each(
                    function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        if($this.is(":checked")){
                            ids.push($this.attr("id").replace("tdCheckbox_",""));
                        }
                    }
                );

                $("#Ids").val(ids);
                $("#submitForm").submit();
            }
        });
}

<g:formRemote name="submitForm"  url="[controller:'myController', action:'submit']" onSuccess="removeIds(data)">
    <g:hiddenField name="Ids" />
</g:formRemote>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
def submit(){
        def result = [success:false]
        if(params?.Ids){
            String[] ids = params?.Ids
            ids.eachWithIndex{ it, int i ->
                //HERE OUTPUT IS LIKE 
                //4 
                //,
                //5
                //,
                //6
                println(it.value)
            }

            result["id"] = params?.Ids
        }

        render result as JSON
    }
```

In eachWithIndex loop i'm getting output with , (comma) that I do not require, I think there must be a good option to loop through it.

Please suggest the same.

Comment: I believe this question should belong to codereview comunity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem that you submitting from javascript one string value (ids delimited with coma)

```
ids=1,2,33
```

and on the level of groovy/grails the `params?.Ids` returns you just a String like this: `"1,2,33"`

and assigning a `String` to a `String[]` just splits it by chars...

as workaround in groovy you can use `params?.Ids?.split(',')`

```
String[] ids = "1,2,33".split(',')
```

or submit multiple values form javascript like this:

```
ids=1 & ids=2 & ids=33
```

in this case grails will return you an array for `params?.Ids` expression if more then one value submitted with the same name

Comment: Shouldn't params.list('Ids') do the trick?  

Edit:  also - the ajax tags have been deprecated - I'd suggest thinking about a migration strategy for those.